# Value Error when attempting to create new column in Python

Tags: python, distance, latitude-longitude, calculated-columns, valueerror

I am attempting to create a new column in my dataframe that shows the distance between a set latitude and longitude against the latitude and longitude for each row in my dataframe using the line of code below:

df["dist_diff"] = geopy.distance.geodesic((place_lat, place_lon), (df_cat['lat'],df_cat['lng'])).miles

Unfortunately, the above code results in a value error as seen below:

ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Comment: I think we would need to know what value df_cat['lat'],df_cat['lng'] has. Because i cant see any obvious problems. Also does this help?: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36921951/truth-value-of-a-series-is-ambiguous-use-a-empty-a-bool-a-item-a-any-o

Comment: df_cat['lat'] and df_cat['lng'] are numeric latitude and longitude values from my dataframe. The place_lat and place_lon are set latitude and longitude values which are defined earlier in the code. Each row in my dataframe as a latitude and longitude.

Comment: Are you sure that the cause of this error is in this line?

Comment: I'm afraid that link doesn't help me. It seems to explain things when you're wanting a boolean and employing a comparison. I am trying to get a column of numeric values using a calculation. Maybe the two are connected, but I am not connecting those dots.  :/

Comment: I am. That is the only line in that part of my little IBM notebook thingy. Everything in the cells above ran fine and appeared to look as I wanted.

Comment: Please provide the entire error message, as well as a [mcve].

Comment: That is a link to the notebook.

Comment: looks like I needed to loop over values, though it appears that I get a warning now